# Python on windows usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, windows, printing, usb, pos

I just try to connect to my Epson TM-T88V using python PyUsb typing this code:

```
import usb.core
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x04b8, idProduct=0x0202)
dev.set_configuration()
```

and received this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
> <module>   File
> "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py",
> line 869, in set_configuration
>     self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py",
> line 102, in wrapper
>     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py",
> line 147, in managed_set_configuration
>     self.managed_open()   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py",
> line 102, in wrapper
>     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py",
> line 120, in managed_open
>     self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py",
> line 786, in open_device
>     return _DeviceHandle(dev)   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py",
> line 643, in __init__
>     _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))   File "C:\Users\miklo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py",
> line 595, in _check
>     raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret]) usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Myabe someone can help to fing a right solution.
Thank you

Comment: Instead of using a low-level interface like PyUSB, you can install the vendor's device driver and use it as a serial port device.

Comment: I'm not actually know how to use printer driver in python... I install vendor's device driver like windows default printer and it's works. but how it use in python ...

Comment: If you just want to communicate with the printer, you can do it with [pySerial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/). If you want to use the printer's print control sequence, you can do some things with a library like [python-escpos](https://pypi.org/project/python-escpos/).